# How to identify different classes of characters within a string in java

Tags: java, character-encoding

I'm building a program for homework and I want to differentiate the characters in a string that is composed of numbers and some other characters in order to do something.
Like, if a character of that string represents an integer, do something, else, do another thing. How can I do that? Is that possible?

Comment: You can use Reflection to identify the data type of a variable at runtime.

Comment: If you provide some code, people will be able to help you.

Comment: `You can use Reflection` ... you want to use reflection to find out that the 3rd character in "1a2b3c" is a number or not?

Comment: @curiosa, in that context, the answer is no. I mean if the variable is String someObj = "abcd"; we can use reflection.

Comment: Yes is possible with Reflection as others mentioned. Just curious why would you like to have an array with numbers and charcters?

Comment: @darmis would you please demonstrate how reflection will help you to find out that the 3rd character in "1a2b3c" is a number or not?

Comment: @curiosa actually a regular expression would fit better as solution for this specific problem, but if the code is packed in a `dll` (.jar in Java world) you could probably use something like `GetType()` ex: ``` int i = 42;
System.Type type = i.GetType();
 ``` that is for C# but I think you have `getClass` in the Java world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write a very simple `regular expression` to check for items of your string list.
for example write it and check all of your items.

```
public static boolean isInteger(String strNum) {
    return strNum.matches("\d+");
}
```

Comment: what does the \d+ mean?

Comment: \d is a digit (a character in the range 0-9). + Means One or more . Together it means one or more digits.

Comment: hmm, my code didnt recognize the strNum library, do I need to import it?

Comment: strNum is a String value. It doesn't need to import anything.